# How to run flush_rewrite_rules on plugin deactivation

Tags: wordpress

I would like my plugin, upon deactivation, to remove/flush the rewrite rules that it is setting.  Here is what I have.  I am not sure why, even with the plugin deactivated, the rewrite rules still work.

Thanks

```
<?php
if(!class_exists('MyPlugin'))
{
    class MyPlugin
    {

        public function __construct() {
            add_action('init', array( &$this, 'add_rewrite_rule' ) );
            add_action('init', array( &$this, 'add_rewrite_tag' ) );
        } 

        public static function activate() {  } 

        public static function deactivate() {
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        } 

        public function add_rewrite_rule(){
            global $wp_rewrite;
            add_rewrite_rule('^content/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?page_id=10&myuniquepid=$matches[1]','top');
            $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
        }

        public function add_rewrite_tag(){
            add_rewrite_tag('%myuniquepid%','([^&]+)');
        }

    } // END class MyPlugin
} // END if(!class_exists('MyPlugin'))

if(class_exists('MyPlugin'))
{
    // Installation and uninstallation hooks
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('MyPlugin', 'activate'));
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('MyPlugin', 'deactivate'));

    // instantiate the plugin class
    $myplugin = new MyPlugin();
}
```

Comment: You have a dollar sign before the flush function `$flush_rewrite_rules();` - what is it for ?

Comment: @Shazzad - That would be a typo!

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule()` method is flushing rewrite with init. This is obviously a wrong approach, [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules). Correcting this could solve the issue, as it's being called after plugin deactivation call completes (on init). So the data again being saved back with the `add_rewrite_rule()`.

Comment: So are you saying that `add_rewrite_rule` should not be called on `init` ?  What should it be called on?  Or should I be moving the `flush_rules()` bit out of the `add_rewrite_function`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, i meant the second one "moving the flush_rules() bit out of the add_rewrite_function". Try adding it on the activation or completely ignore it and use the permalink setting page to flush once if required.

Comment: @Shazzad - I tried moving `global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` up to the `activate()` function but that didn't work either.  I've been trying to find an example online to draw from but not having much success.

Comment: I tested and couldn't come to a conclusion, but if you want to follow up my research check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88045) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133908). And bear in mind that the rules are added to `extra_rules_top` and not `non_wp_rules`.

Answer (score 1):

**Important**

As mentioned in the comments, make sure you only flush_rewrite_rules when it's needed. This is an expensive operation so it should only be used when absolutely necessary.

**The problem**

`register_activation_hook()` runs **before** `init` & `plugins_loaded` actions.

`register_deactivation_hook()` runs **after** `init` & `plugins_loaded` actions.

This is great if you want to handle DB creation/remove stuff, not when we want to add or clean-up rewrite rules.

Most plugins use `init` or `plugins_loaded` actions to load everything and generate rewrite rules. The activation hook is called before this.

The deactivation hook runs late in the cycle so your rewrite_rules logic is processed and are also added on deactivation, nothing is cleaned.

**A possible solution**

Below a very basic plugin example that handles flush_rewrite_rules on the (de)activation action. Not tested, I put this together from a plugin i'm building.

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Flush Rewrite Rules testing
  Plugin URI: https://fake.com
  Description: flsuh rewrite rules on activation/deactivation
  Version: 0.0.1
  Author: Bjorn
  Author URI: https://fake.com
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'frrt_activation');
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'frrt_deactivation');
add_action('init', 'frrt_flush_rewrite_rules');

function frrt_activation() {
  if ( ! get_option( 'frrt_flush_rewrite_rules_flag' ) ) add_option( 'frrt_flush_rewrite_rules_flag', true );
}

function frrt_deactivation() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function frrt_flush_rewrite_rules() {
  if( get_option( 'frrt_flush_rewrite_rules_flag' ) ) {
    add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'frrt_generate_rewrite_rules');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    delete_option( 'frrt_flush_rewrite_rules_flag' );
  }
}

function frrt_generate_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
    ['some-base-url/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?example_query_var=$matches[1]'],
    $wp_rewrite->rules
  );
}
```

On activation set a flag (option) so we can generate & flush the rewrite rules on the `init` action. The deactivation works as expected because we only generate rewrite rules on activation.

I don't think this is ideal at all, because we do a db query (`get_option()`) on every `init` action, which 99,9999% of the time is not needed...
But it's the only workaround that worked for me.

WP does not consider this to be a bug, see this [Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42563).

If someone has a better solution please share ;-).